# Is it ok to repeat a question 12 hours later?

Tags: support, asking-questions

For most of my questions, I get an answer within 10 minutes...
After 12 hours almost nobody sees my question anymore...
I would like to know what is the time limit to repeat a question....

Comment: The time limit to post same question again is infinity.

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/152859), more than that you can't and shouldn't do..

Comment: Too late, really. OP posted their duplicate before they asked this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't repeat a question ever. It would be marked as a duplicate and get closed. You can edit your question with some more details; that would bump it up the list. If the edit is sufficient, it should attract more attention and hopefully an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot repost a question, it will either be automatically prevented or it will be manually closed by moderators/users.

If it didn't get an answer on one day then reposting it isn't going to help. You need to improve the question so that it is more answerable, offer a bounty on it to get it more attention, or just accept that it's not going to get an answer and sadly just accept it.

It might get an answer 1 day later, 5 days, 5 months, 5 years. It's not a support forum where you can expect answers reasonably quickly, you get them when you get them.

Comment: "or just accept that it's not going to get an answer and sadly just accept it." just accept that you accept it?

Comment: @Pow-Ian  I accept your point.

Comment: @Pow-Ian Can't you accept that he accepts that he accepts it?

Comment: I sure can accept that he accepts the fact that he is accepting that he accepted it.

Comment: @Pow I accept you accept he accepts he is accepting he accepted it.